# Looking for an offline dictionary

Tags: translation, resources

I currently have a .txt file containing a list of approximately different 20,000 Italian words, likely including many conjugations of the same root, that I need to translate into English. Is there any free offline (or online if it will let me do that many words at once) utility that I can use for this or is there a .csv with translations that I could use?

I really don't want to have to translate them by hand or cut it into hundreds of parts and use Google Translate (then have to correct it when it's unable to translate, e.g., "galantuomini").

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I'm not sure there's such a resource, but have you tried to [download Wiktionary's database](https://calc.hypotheses.org/32)? They have a fairly extensive coverage

Comment: There is also the problem that many words can have different translations based on context (hence the famous bon mot *Amare significa poco dolci*), which will further complicate your task.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, I don't need a one to one list. It also doesn't have to be perfect, I'd be perfectly fine with a single definition for each word since the number of words with different translations is small compared with set of all words.